# .NET RegEx letters/signs/spaces

Tags: c#, .net, regex

I have to allow all letters (including accents) = `\w`

I have to allow spaces = `\s`

I have to allow specific signs = `[\-\/\.\;\\\,\:\+\(\)]`

The only limitation is that these signs can appear max 3 times in the complete string.

At the moment I have this regex

`^\w*([\-\/\.\;\\\,\:\+\(\)\s]{0,3}\w*){0,2}?$`

But, this limits everything to a certain point. Can anyone support me to create the correct regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you do not need `\w`, you need `\p{L}` to match *letters only*. Note that `\w` matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`, and is thus not suitable for this scenario.

Combine all into 1 pattern - `^[-\p{L}\s/.;\\,:+()]+$` - and restrict it with a `(?!(?:[^-/.;\\,:+()]*[-/.;\\,:+()]){4})` negative lookahead anchored at the start disallowing 4 non-consecutive occurrences of these special symbols (so, allowing 0-3 occurrences):

```
\A(?!(?:[^-/.;\\,:+()]*[-/.;\\,:+()]){4})[-\p{L}\s/.;\\,:+()]+\z
```

See the [regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%28%3f!%28%3f%3a%5b%5e%2f.%3b%5c%5c%2c%3a%2b%28%29%5cr%5cn-%5d*%5b-%2f.%3b%5c%5c%2c%3a%2b%28%29%5d%29%7b4%7d%29%5b-%5cp%7bL%7d+%2f.%3b%5c%5c%2c%3a%2b%28%29%5d%2b%5cr%3f%24&i=a+-+b+-+c+-+d+-%0d%0aa+-+b+-+c+-+d%0d%0aa+%28+b+%29+c+%2c+d+%2f&o=m)

- `\A` - start of string
- `(?!(?:[^-/.;\\,:+()]*[-/.;\\,:+()]){4})` - a negative lookahead that fails the match if its pattern matches:

  - `(?:[^-/.;\\,:+()]*[-/.;\\,:+()]){4}` - 4 sequences of:

    - `[^-/.;\\,:+()]*` - zero or more chars other than those defined in the set
    - `[-/.;\\,:+()]` - 1 char defined in the set
- `[-\p{L}\s/.;\\,:+()]+` - 1 or more chars defined in the character class
- `\z` - the very end of string.

C# declaration using a verbatim string literal:

```
var pattern = @"\A(?!(?:[^-/.;\\,:+()]*[-/.;\\,:+()]){4})[-\p{L}\s/.;\\,:+()]+\z";
```

Another approach: use a non-capturing group and apply the `{0,3}` limiting quantifier to it:

```
\A[\p{L}\s]*(?:[-/.;\\,:+()][\p{L}\s]*){0,3}[\p{L}\s]*\z
```

See [another regex demo](http://regexstorm.net/tester?p=%5e%5b%5cp%7bL%7d+%5d*%28%3f%3a%5b-%2f.%3b%5c%5c%2c%3a%2b%28%29%5d%5b%5cp%7bL%7d+%5d*%29%7b0%2c3%7d%5b%5cp%7bL%7d+%5d*%5cr%3f%24&i=a+-+b+-+c+-+d+-%0d%0aa+-+b+-+c+-+d%0d%0aa+%28+b+%29+c+%2c+d+%2f&o=m). Note this expression will also match an empty string,  to prevent it, replace the first or last `[\p{L}\s]*` with `[\p{L}\s]+`.

- `[\p{L}\s]*` - matches 0+ letter or whitespace chars
- `(?:[-/.;\\,:+()][\w\s]*){0,3}` -  0 to 3 occurrences of:

  - `[-/.;\\,:+()]` - 1 char from the set
  - `[\p{L}\s]*` - 0+ letter or whitespace chars
- `[\p{L}\s]*` - matches 0+ word or whitespace chars

Comment: Thanks for your reply! Your last update seems a bit more clear to me. Is there also any way to fail on digits? Because \w allows digits too (which I didn't notice before). Thanks again for the effort and explanation already!

Comment: Well, `\w` matches `[\p{L}\p{N}_]`. Just replace `\w` with whatever you need: `[\p{L}_]` if you also need underscores, or just `\p{L}` to only match letters.